# Date format in LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, telerik

i got problem with my LINQ to format date. Here is code

```
 var resultCustomer = from row in formDg.dtCustomer.AsEnumerable()
                          where row.Field<int>("customerID") == customerID2
                          select new
                          {
                              name = row["customerName"].ToString(),
                              ic = row["customerIC"].ToString(),
                              add1 = row["customerAdd1"].ToString(),
                              add2 = row["customerAdd2"].ToString(),
                              tel = row["customerTel"].ToString(),
                              tel2 = row["customerTel2"].ToString(),
                              tel3 = row["customerTel3"].ToString(),
                              email = row["customerEmail"].ToString(),
                              dateRegister = row["customerDateRegister"].ToString(),
                              customerRef = row["customerRef"].ToString(),
                              customerGroup = row["groupCustName"].ToString(),
                              panelName = row["panelName"].ToString(),
                              };

var firstRecord = resultCustomer.First();// My record return single row only
```

My question is how i can format custom date like "dd/MM/yyyy" in **customerDateRegister?**, Because I got problem when my textbox show **16-Nov-12 12:00:00 AM**. I don`t want to display time but just date only.

I have try like this **tbDateRegOv.Text = firstRecord.dateRegister.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");**. not work. Then i try **dateRegister = row["customerDateRegister"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),** in LINQ. Same problem.

So how can I solved this problem? Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast your row as a `DateTime` first. This will allow you to use the custom format strings for dates.

```
dateRegister = ((DateTime)row["customerDateRegister"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. If you don't mind can show example code?

Comment: Sorry for editing this answer instead of mine. That was just an accident.

Comment: This depends on the `CurrentCulture` because `/` in the format string represents the `DateSeparator` string of the culture. If you do want dependence of culture, I suggest you use `.ToString("d")` instead because it also has the "endianness" and other stuff agreeing with the culture. If you **don't** want dependence of culture, either say `.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy")` with escaped slashes, or use an overload that takes in the `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 2):

If `customerDateRegister` is of type `DateTime` you should make it a `DateTime` in the first place. Therefor use the `DataRow` extension method [`Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx):

```
dateRegister = row.Field<DateTime>("customerDateRegister")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this , replace your dateRegister line with this.

```
dateRegister = ((DateTime)row["customerDateRegister"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use MaskedEditBox with the desired datetime mask